# Change color of span if checkbox is selected

Tags: html, css

In to-do list apps, if you finish to-do the color of text changes.
I'm trying to make that, but there is issue.
How can I make this with only pure css?

```css
.todo-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.todo-item div {
  position: relative;
}

.todo-item div input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.todo-item div {
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item div input[type=checkbox]:checked+div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo-item">
  <span>If checkbox is selected, color of this text need to be changed to green.</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="white">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` is on a higher level than the `input` in the DOM hierarchy, and since there [is no CSS parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), it is not possible with just CSS.

If you don't want to modify your current HTML structure, here's a JavaScript solution which listens for a `change` event and checks whether the input is checked, and if so, sets the `color` style property of the span to green:

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  span.style.color = input.checked ? "green" : "black";
})
```

```css
.todo-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.todo-item div {
  position: relative;
}

.todo-item div input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.todo-item div {
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item div input[type=checkbox]:checked+div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo-item">
  <span>If checkbox is selected, color of this text need to be changed to green.</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="white">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place span **after** input in code and show it before input with **flex order**. You'll be able to style span text with **~** selector as you already do for fake checkbox

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.checkbox-styled {
  order: 2;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-styled {
  background-color: black;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
  color: green;
}

span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="checkbox-styled">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="white">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span>If checkbox is selected, color of this text need to be changed to green.</span>
</label>
```